# Task manager fails to load after power outage

Tags: windows-7, boot, task-manager

Recently I had a power outage while watching a movie. With the power back on, Windows doesn't load as expected.

Symptoms are:

- Windows 7 taskbar appears, but program icons and Recycle Bin don't;
- I can't launch the task manager;
- The mouse indicates endless processes.

Loading windows in Safe Mode and then running System Restore helps, but that's not a good option.

Is it a virus, or has Windows crashed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot off the Windows 7 disk. It has some tools to try to auto-repair corrupted Windows files, which could be causing this issue. It also has some nice diagnostics on there. I would try letting Windows fix the issues. If that fails, you can try running `chkdsk /r` from the Windows 7 disk on your main drive to try to recover corrupt sectors and see if that helps.

Comment: could you provide some extra information on the tools and how do I use them. I would be very appreciated!

Comment: Assuming you have a Windows 7 disk, put it in the drive and reboot the computer. When it is booting up, you'll see something along the lines of "Press any key to boot from CD/DVD...". Press anything on the keyboard and it will load up. Click on **Repair your computer** then **System Restore**. This should restore your computer for you.

If that doesn't work, boot up to the Windows 7 DVD again, click **Repair** again, then click on **Command Prompt** then type in `chkdsk c:\ /rf`